# Makefile match patterns in rule and recipe

Tags: c++, bash, makefile

I have a pattern emerging for my tests in my makefile. I'm aware of the pattern matchers `%` and `$<`. I'm trying to compile some C++.

I have a snippet of a makefile that looks like:

```
diff-test: main-test.o diff.o test/diff-test.cpp 
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $(BOOST_LINK_FLAGS) build/main-test.o build/diff.o test/diff-test.cpp -o build/diff-test
    build/diff-test

walk-test: main-test.o walk.o test/walk-test.cpp
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $(BOOST_LINK_FLAGS) build/main-test.o build/%.o test/%-test.cpp -o build/%-test
    build/walk-test
```

I tried something along the lines of:

```
%-test: main-test.o %.o test/%-test.cpp 
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $(BOOST_LINK_FLAGS) build/main-test.o build/$<.o test/$<-test.cpp -o build/$<-test
    build/$<-test
```

But that just couldn't match the tests I wanted:

```
make diff-test
make: *** No rule to make target `diff-test'.  Stop.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want `$<`.  That expands to the first prerequisite which in this case is `main-test.o` which means you'll be building `build/main-test.o-test` using `main-test.o.o` and `test/main-test.o-test.cpp` which seems highly unlikely.

You probably mean `$*` instead.

However you can't use automatic variables in prerequisite lists: they are only defined inside the recipe itself.

Why not use the pattern in the prerequisite list; that's how pattern rules are supposed to work:

```
%-test: %.o test/%-test.cpp main-test.o
        $(CC) $(FLAGS) $(BOOST_LINK_FLAGS) $^ -o build/$*-test
        build/$*-test
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked. I appreciate the extra tip for `$^` as well :)